# How do I trigger a Github action if a file is not touched?

Tags: github, github-actions

I would like to trigger a [Github action](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions) if the `Pipfile` is not touched.

I can do something like

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths-ignore:
      - Pipfile*
```

but if a PR touches the `Pipfile` along with another non-`Pipfile` file, then the action triggers.

Is this possible?

Comment: To be sure that I understood you. You want to have workflow run when non-`Pipfile` is changed, right?

Comment: I want to have a workflow run when a `Pipfile` is not changed. It is a subtle difference but it matters.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? For instance with example folder/file structure?

Comment: Two files: `Pipfile` and `foo.py`. If only `foo.py` is modified, then action triggers. If only `Pipfile` is modified, then action doesn't trigger. If both `foo.py` and `Pipfile` is modified, then action doesn't trigger.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not possible. You can only break a workflow if `Pipefile` is changed.

Answer (score 1):

> Two files: Pipfile and foo.py. If only foo.py is modified, then action triggers. If only Pipfile is modified, then action doesn't trigger. If both foo.py and Pipfile is modified, then action doesn't trigger

This is not possible, but what you need is actually a check step to see what file was changed and then exit workflow if `Pipfile` was changed. You can do this using this command

`git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${{ github.sha }}`

Comment: This triggers even if the `Pipfile` is modified, which is not what I want.